# How to extract data from one to another string and save to the output

Tags: sed, awk, grep, tr

Want to get specific hour to another and save output. First hour is my start point for example:

```
Nov 20 13:42:52 host sendmail[14819]: qAKCgpxF014819: Milter: read returned -1: Connection reset by mail.yahoo.com
```

And my finish point is:

```
Nov 20 16:22:23 host sendmail[16326]: qAKCgpxF016326: Milter: read returned -1: Connection reset by mail.yahoo.com
```

I need to save all data from my start point to my finish point into file only.

Comment: How do you plan to do, in one line? or you plan to make in some steps

Comment: Actually I need only output from starting of this hour to the end hour nothing more, just check maillog and want to extract data from first point to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the records are sorted by time, you can just

```
sed -n '/^Nov 20 13:42:52/,/^Nov 20 16:22:23/p' input.log > output.log
```

Beware, if there are more records with the end time, only the first one will be printed. You can improve it by

```
sed -n '/start/,/end/{p;d};/end/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

does this work for you? (didn't test)

```
awk -F' |:'  'BEGIN{m="Nov";d=20;sh=13;eh=16}$1==m && $2==d && $3>=sh && $3<=eh' file
```